# Text over symbols, but with adjusting width ( something like \stackrel{#1}{#2} but with same size)

Tags: math-mode, symbols, relation-symbols

I would like to write something above equation sign. One may do it with `\stack{#1}{#2}` command and it works fine if #1 and #2 are the same length, example:

```
$\stackrel{(3)}{=}$
```

will result in

[image]

But if I would like to have longer text above =, for example:

```
$\stackrel{x_1 \neq x_2}{=}$
```

then I will get

[image]

which is not what I want.

I want the "=" to adjust it's size to the thing that's written above, so something like

[image]

Is there a command which will do it automaticaly? Or if not - how can i do it manually?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your question has already appeared. If the linked question helps, fine; otherwise, add to your question the reasons why it doesn't. Closing as duplicate is non a judgment on your question, just a way to keep information as tight as possible.

Comment: Yeah looks like the link which You gave contains solution to my question, too bad I wasn't able to find it before.

Thanks for quick response :)